# rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials [Package not found]

Tags: ros, catkin-create-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm really new at using ROS and I was doing some tutorials.

The tutorial I'm actually stuck on is the following:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage

I have a problem when I do the following command :

```
`rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials`
```

I have the following error :

`[rospack] Error: no such package beginner_tutorials`

So I'm wondering why since the command I ran previously to this one was :

`$ catkin_create_pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp`

This command should create the package but it apparently doesn't. I'm wondering what I missed.

When I tried the command :

`roswtf`

This is what it return :

`Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf`

`Package: beginner_tutorials`

`Cannot find dependencies for package [beginner_tutorials]: missing beginner_tutorials`

`ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros`

`ROS path [1]=/home/anon/catkin_ws/src`

`ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/indigo/share`

`ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/indigo/stacks`

Does anybody understand my mistake ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196349/rospack-depends1-beginner_tutorials-%5Bpackage-not-found%5D/) by [jbsubils](https://answers.ros.org/users/20640/jbsubils/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok so I understood my problem.

The solution is before to do the command:

$ catkin_create_pkg beginner_tutorials std_msgs rospy roscpp

We need to be located in :
~/catkin_ws/src

For some reason I was in ~/catkin_ws and thought it was the right place to create the Package.

---

Originally posted by [jbsubils](https://answers.ros.org/users/20640/jbsubils/) with karma: 26 on 2014-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might need to rebuild your workspace before your new package is findable:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws
catkin_make
. devel/setup.bash
rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials
```

(If this works, please let me know and I'll update the tutorial)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbsubils](https://answers.ros.org/users/20640/jbsubils/) on 2014-10-30**:
No, I still have the same error

**Comment by [jbsubils](https://answers.ros.org/users/20640/jbsubils/) on 2014-10-30**:
I don't understand the response of this question (which is the same than mine):
http://answers.ros.org/question/99551/rospack-cant-find-package-created-with-catkin_create_package/

**Comment by [Rutger](https://answers.ros.org/users/27888/rutger/) on 2016-09-03**:
This did do the trick for me, thanks!